# Pass an expression to tokenize()

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route that consumes a file and splits it:

```
from("file:etc.")
.split(body().tokenize("\n", 100, false)).streaming()
```

The second parameter is set to a constant 100. Is there a way to have it wary, based on the file. For instance, just before I hit the "split" I could set a value in the header, and it would be cool if I could then do:

```
.split(body().tokenize("\n", simple("...pull header value..."), false))
```

but, tokenize() needs an integer, not an expression.

Is there a neat way to achieve what I want: varying the value of 'group'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen that you can pass expressions to your tokenize method. However you can do like this:

```
.split().method("mySplitterBean", "splitBody")
```

Pass the entire exchange and then you can access the headers and properties. 
See an example here under streaming mode pojo;
http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html

Comment: Yes you would need to call a method and then from that method you can create an iterator that splits the body in the number of elements as you want. For example you can create an instance of the org.apache.camel.util.GroupIterator which is what that tokenizer would do